# Writing in a CSV variables captured from every JSON in current dir

Tags: python, json, with-statement, os.walk

I'm trying to go thru every json file in my current directory and find two specific variables, productId and userProfileId (both are getting well captured on the output file) but cant get it to run for every file in the folder.

This is my best try so far

```
import json
import csv
import os

KEYS = ['user_id','product_id']

for files in os.walk("."):  
    for filename in files:
        for i in filename:
            if i.endswith(".json"):
                print(i)
                with open(i) as json_data:
                    order_parsed = json.load(json_data)
                    products_data = order_parsed['items']
                    user_data = order_parsed['clientProfileData']

                with open('user-item.csv','w') as dataFile:
                    newFileWriter = csv.writer(dataFile)
                    newFileWriter.writerow(KEYS)
                    for item in products_data:
                        productId = (products_data[0]['productId'])
                        userId = (user_data["userProfileId"])
                        print(productId)
                        print(userId)
                        newFileWriter.writerow([userId,productId])
```

Answer (score 1):

To loop though all files in a folder, you can use this for.

```
for file in os.listdir('folder_path'):
    if file[-5:] == ".json": 
        arq = open(file,'r')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a dictionary key search under the with loop. Try not doing your search under the with loop by unindenting products_data and user_data once.

Comment: corrected it but still receiveing the same issue. Cant get the json.load the files triggered by the for loop

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser2.py", line 15, in <module>
    order_parsed = json.load(file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'`